# Reading output of a C++ DLL using JNA

Tags: java, c++, dll, stdout, jna

I have a the following "system":

C++ DLL -> C DLL -> Java with JNA

The C++ DLL is a third party DLL, that I wanted to use with Java using JNA. But JNA works better with C than C++, so I made a C wrapper that load the C++ DLL (using LoadLibrary), then in Java, with JNA, I load the C DLL and access to the functions exported by the C wrapper.

I guess there may be better design to work with C++ DLL in Java, but this is not my point here, and it seems to work.

My problem is that the C++ DLL writes on stdout and stderr, but the messages written by the C++ DLL are not displayed in the Java console, though the messages written by the C wrapper are displayed. What is the solution to read the output of the C++ DLL from Java ?

So far I tried to make a "test wrapper" in C++, which directly loads the C++ DLL using LoadLibrary and use its functions, the output of the C++ DLL was then displayed correctly.

Then I tried to call freopen() to redirect the stdout to a file from the C wrapper. When using the "test wrapper", the output of the C++ DLL is redirect to the file, but when calling the C wrapper from JNA, only the output of the C wrapper and of Java are redirected to the file (output of the C++ DLL is ignored).

The C++ DLL is compiled with MSVC 2013, and the C DLL wrapper too. I am working with Windows 7.

Comment: Code is better than 1000 words. Provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Keep in mind that the JVM may be doing some redirection of C or C++ output streams that won't be present in your raw C/C++ program.  By "Java Console", I take it you mean the terminal in which you launch your JVM?